# Hooking Printf-like function and modifying output

Tags: c, printf, hook, variadic-functions

I'm hooking printf-like function that is defined like this:

```
int Con_Printf(const char *format, ...)
```

I want to check if a given string is within the arguments or in the final formatted string and if is there, then replace it with another string, but I have the following code to pass the arguments to the original function:

```
va_list args;
char *parg;

va_start(args, format);
vasprintf(&parg, format, args);
va_end(args);

(*conprint)("%s", parg);
free(parg);
```

being (*conprint) the original Con_Printf function.

How can I view the string with format applied (i.e arguments replaced into placeholders) to replace what I need and not just pass through all the arguments?

Example:
The program calls Con_Printf("%s %s", "foo", "bar"), I want to know in my Con_Printf hook if "bar" is within the arguments, but I don't know how many arguments are there because of the ", ...)" definition of Con_Printf.

If "bar" is found within the arguments, then replace it for "baz" and forward a modified call (*conprint)("%s %s", "foo", "baz") (replaced bar with baz). (*conprint)("foo baz") would do the trick too.

Thanks!

Comment: You should initialize `parg=NULL;`. BTW, your question is unclear, so edit it. Please give an example of expected behavior.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by `view the string after formatting`?

Comment: edited to add more information, @SouravGhosh, I meant to be able to manipulate the string after format is applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, what you want is `va_arg()`. Check the man page [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/va_arg). Instead of directly using `vasprintf()`, you may want to

1. take out one argument at a time
2. perform required checks and operations
3. then put them together for the final `conprint`.

from the manual page, the historic setup is:

```
#include <varargs.h>

void foo(va_alist)
    va_dcl
{
    va_list ap;

   va_start(ap);
    while (...) {
        ...
        x = va_arg(ap, type);
        ...
    }
    va_end(ap);
}
```

<sup>You need to choose the `type` based on the supplied format specifier</sup>

Comment: I did read about that while searching about my issue; to do this I should have to know how many arguments are there, being that number the count of placeholders at format. Manually parsing placeholders would be very tricky, i'm not sure if is there other way by using this method on a function that I can't change

Comment: @Rodrigo NO, IMO, you don't need to bother about number of arguments. Just keep on looping till you vave a valid `fmt` value.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think I missed the fact that the string part should contain the already formatted text, so I could directly do string manipulation on there to replace the needle.

So, my code finally ended like this:

```
va_list args;
char *parg;

va_start(args, format);
vasprintf(&parg, format, args);
va_end(args);

char* replacedstr;
replacedstr =  str_replace(parg, "bar", "baz");
(*conprint)("%s", replacedstr); 
free(parg);
```

Being str_replace a nice function that I've found somewhere (I've never coded in C, just doing experiments).

Answer (score -1):

```
static (*__cdecl)F_HOOK *edit_f(&printf, sizeof(printf))
{
    __cdecl _:printf
    {
    /* .. code before executing printf stuff.. */
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @viewer, adding some code without context is not the best helpful way. Please take your time to elaborate your answer and explaining what is happening.